# Upload failed. The error message was: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constant violation:

Tags: craft3, error-message, mysql

I'm getting this strange error when I'm trying to upload an .jpg in the assets.

Env: Localhost
Craft version 3.1.8

MAMP:
- PHP(7.2.7)
- MySQL: 5.7.21

Upload failed. The error message was: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constant violation:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does this only happen with this one particular image? If so, try renaming the image file to golden-pothos-2.jpg or something and then uploading again.

Answer (score 1):

Do as Jon mentioned. This was a bug that will be fixed in the next release https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/3773